# Python Social Auth, Extending Disconnect Pipeline

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have a user profile table and it has fb_id, tw_id. So I am checking if users connected their social accounts. I need to update these columns when user disconnects one of their accounts.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.get_entries',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.revoke_tokens',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.disconnect',
    'profiles.utils.disconnect',
)
```

So I added a function named disconnect in my profile app as it refers [here](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline).

```
def disconnect(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if Profiles.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        if backend.name == 'facebook':
            profile=Profiles.objects.get(user=user)
            profile.fb_id = ''
            profile.save()

        if backend.name == 'twitter':
            profile=Profiles.objects.get(user=user)
            profile.tw_id = ''
            profile.save()

        if backend.name == 'instagram':
            profile=Profiles.objects.get(user=user)
            new_profile.in_id = ''
            profile.save()
```

When I try to disconnect my account I get this error:

```
TypeError at /disconnect/facebook/
disconnect() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    /disconnect/facebook/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
disconnect() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

This is first time I use python_social_auth, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.get_entries',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.revoke_tokens',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.disconnect',
    'profiles.utils.disconnect',
)
```

And revised the function as this:

```
def disconnect(strategy, entries, *args, **kwargs):
    backend = kwargs.get('name')

    profile=Profiles.objects.get(user=entries[0].user)
    if backend == 'facebook':
        profile.fb_id = False
    elif backend == 'twitter':
        profile.tw_id = False
    elif backend == 'instagram':
        new_profile.in_id = False
    profile.save()
```

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.get_entries',
    'social.pipeline.disconnect.revoke_tokens',
    # 'social.pipeline.disconnect.disconnect',  # comment
    'profiles.utils.custom_pipeline',
)
```

**custom_pipeline.py**

```
def disconnect(strategy, entries, user_storage, *args, **kwargs):        
    for entry in entries:
        user_storage.disconnect(entry)
    backend = kwargs.get('name')

    profile=Profiles.objects.get(user=entries[0].user)
    if backend == 'facebook':
        profile.fb_id = ''
    elif backend == 'twitter':
        profile.tw_id = ''
    elif backend == 'instagram':
        new_profile.in_id = ''
    profile.save()
```

The best!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I tried your solution but I got a new error, it says: list index out of range

Comment: this solution works if you use social auth's own disconnect and delete user_storage from args and for block in the function.